# How to disable windows firewall settings

Tags: windows, com, windows-firewall

I am doing firewall related work.
I can turn ON/OFF windows firewall programatically using COM interface but I want to disable turn ON/OFF options.
Is there any COM interface, Windows API present for that?

Comment: What options are you trying to enable or disable?  The COM API allows for adding, editing, and removing individual rules.  Is that what you mean by "options" or something else?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to stop the user from being able to use the control panel to turn the firewall off?  You can do that with group policy, and I believe it is possible to configure local group policy programmatically, though I'm unfamiliar with the details.  Of course the user will still be able to bypass this if they know what they're doing.

Comment: Yes thats what I mean, to stop the user from being able to use the control panel to turn the firewall off/on.

Answer (score 1):

You can Turn off windows firewall through command line.Just paste this command in your command prompt.

> netsh advfirewall set  currentprofile state off

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is triggered by the presence of Group Policy for the firewall, specifically the [Windows Firewall: Protect all Network connections](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457149.aspx) setting.

As per [How to disable Windows Firewall using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104033/how-to-disable-windows-firewall-using-python/35165745#35165745), you need to enable this setting in any of the available ways outlined there.