# How to disable Windows Firewall using python

Tags: python, windows, firewall, activepython

I am trying to write automation to a little project that I'm doing in work.
In the proccess I need to disable Windows Firewall (for every Windows version) **using python** (I prefer activepython because it already installed).

I looked for many answers but I didn't found any answer that suits my needs.

I found this site:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2012-July/012434.html
But the problem is that when I check from the control panel the actual
disabling of Firewall is not happening...

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Please state "your needs" for us to be able to guess what might "suit" them. 1) do you need to stop/disable the Windows Firewall service or set its settings to "off" as seen in `firewall.cpl`? If the latter - for all network interfaces or only specific ones? 2) what are you trying to achieve? There's likely a better way than a Python program (like Group Policy or a regular command line).

Comment: netsh.exe works for me in Windows 10, e.g. `subprocess.check_call('netsh.exe advfirewall set publicprofile state off')`. The default profiles are "domainprofile", "privateprofile", and "publicprofile", and the state is either "on" or "off".

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev  - I need to set it to "off" as seen in firewall.cpl

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it would be using `WMI`:

```
import wmi,os

c = wmi.WMI("WinMgmts:\root\Microsoft\HomeNet")

for obj in c.HNet_ConnectionProperties():
    print obj
    print obj.IsFirewalled
    obj.IsFirewalled = False
    obj.Put_()
```

Of course to do this you will need to be running the program as an administrator.

Hope this helps,

Jason.

Comment: This disables FW for each connection ("advanced" tab in UI) rather than globally.

Answer (score 2):

Ways to control Windows Firewall - both with UI and programmatically - are covered extensively in the [Windows Firewall Tools and Settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737845%28WS.10%29.aspx) MSDN article. They are:

- Registry settings at

  - `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\<profile>` (local settings) and
  - `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\<profile>` (group policy settings).

  Changing a setting has an instant effect: the Firewall service sets up notifications for the keys apparently.
- Facilities that work with the settings:

  - COM interface `HNetCfg.FwMgr`
  - `netsh firewall` (`netsh advfirewall` for Advanced Firewall)
  - WMI `winmgmts:root/Microsoft/HomeNet`
  - `%windir%\Inf\Netfw.inf` (absent unless created manually)

`firewall.cpl` reflects the local registry settings (or overriding Group Policy ones if they are present [and doesn't allow to change them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022533/how-to-disable-windows-firewall-settings/35164952#35164952)) and the currently active profile (for predefined profiles and how one is selected, see [How Windows Firewall Works](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755604), "Windows Firewall Profile Determination" section for XP/2003 and [Understanding Firewall Profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/getting-started-wfas-firewall-profiles-ipsec%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for Vista+).

Python can work with any of the aforementioned facilities. Though other tools (Group Policy, `.reg` files, `netsh` command line) may be more convenient depending on your task (e.g. `netsh` auto-selects the active profile).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to have another program do the work for you. In this case, netsh.exe has a set of [commands to control the Advanced Firewall](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771920) that's used by Windows Vista and later. For example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call('netsh.exe advfirewall set publicprofile state off')
```

The default profiles are "domainprofile", "privateprofile", and "publicprofile", and the state is either "on" or "off".

Comment: Only works if Advanced Firewall is installed. The profiles names are for Vista+.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, thanks for the catch, I no longer write answers for XP since I don't have an XP VM to test on and, frankly, wouldn't be bothered to do so even if I did. I would not recommend modifying the registry directly, and using COM (e.g. [`INetFwPolicy2`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831755.aspx)) is not something I'd recommend because the light approach, comtypes (extension of ctypes) is a bit half baked, and the alternative, PyWin32, is a large dependency to add to a project, plus there's the cost of learning basic COM programming. Using netsh is simple and reliable.

Answer (score -2):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
State for configuring Windows Firewall
'''


def __virtual__():
'''
Load if the module firewall is loaded
'''
return 'win_firewall' if 'firewall.get_config' in __salt__ else False


def disabled(name):
'''
Disable all the firewall profiles (Windows only)
'''
ret = {'name': name,
       'result': True,
       'changes': {},
       'comment': ''}

# Determine what to do
action = False
current_config = __salt__['firewall.get_config']()
for key in current_config:
    if current_config[key]:
        action = True
        ret['changes'] = {'fw': 'disabled'}
        break

if __opts__['test']:
    ret['result'] = None
    return ret

# Disable it
if action:
    ret['result'] = __salt__['firewall.disable']()
    if not ret['result']:
        ret['comment'] = 'Could not disable the FW'
else:
    ret['comment'] = 'All the firewall profiles are disabled'

return ret
```

Comment: I had a little problem with this code, can you explain what are you doing?


Do I need external modules?